# loosing 1 hour after formatting a date string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

i am formatting a date string with the following code:

and this is the format of the date string : **2013-10-08T20:30:00+03:00**

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];


NSDateFormatter *formmatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formmatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSZZZ";
NSString *dataString = [meetingData objectForKey:@"start"];
if (![dataString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    NSMutableString *mutableDate = [dataString mutableCopy];
    [mutableDate deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(mutableDate.length - 3, 1)];
    NSDate *gmtDate = [formmatter dateFromString:mutableDate];
    NSDateFormatter *HHMM_Fromatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [HHMM_Fromatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    self.meetingTime = checkTheObject([HHMM_Fromatter stringFromDate:gmtDate]);
    self.meetingDay = checkTheObject([dateFormatter stringFromDate:gmtDate]);
}
```

the output is for`self.meetingTime` : 19:30
and `self.meetingDay` is fine, why am i loosing 1 hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two date formatters `HHMM_Fromatter` and `dateFormatter` use different locales and thus, different time zones. You should explicitly set the timezone of both formatters to the same zone (probably `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`).

Note that the remaining parts of your date code seems fragile. You shouldn't do string calculations to remove the time zone from a string representation.

`NSDate` represents an absolute point in time and is not affected by time zones or locales. You should parse the string to one single `NSDate` and then use this date to calculate user facing string representations that take time zones into account.

Comment: but i think the +03:00 (time zone) is dynamic and coming from the server, how can i handle it?

Comment: after setting both to en_US locate the output is the same

Comment: @orazran Of course you have to parse the full time string you get from the server, including the time zone. You have to set up the formatter properly to parse the time zone part. The resulting `NSDate` will always be generic: There's no locale information in this universal representation of a point in time.